# Why do we need to keep declaring basic packages like Using System in .Net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

At the beginning of learning .Net Core and I cannot understand why .cs files need to keep importing system packages when they should be part of .Net Core anyway?

I don't have to import any such things in ColdFusion because System operations and DB connections etc are part of the framework. Surely `System` is part of .Net Core so why do I have to keep adding something as basic as `Using System` to my files?

Comment: This is not **import**! It is just a shorthand. You can simply use fully qualified names, and no `using` caluses at all. Adding references to the project is what you could call importing. But that is managed on project level not file.

Comment: what does that mean? why isnt basic functionality built in to .Net Core so I can use System without having to say it in every file? Its like telling PHP to import String functions in every file when that is a basic thing thats part of PHP.

Comment: Because namespaces were hacked into PHP after years, and C# had them from the beginning.

Comment: Because you may not use stuff from `System` and you may not want unused imports at the top of the file.

Comment: A `using` statement does not import packages, it makes namespaces available. These things are separate. Most classes in `System` *are* part of .NET Core in the sense that no packages at all need to be added to make them available, but you still need to declare the namespace explicitly. Why? Consider a class like `Timer`. Do you want `System.Threading.Timer`, `System.Timers.Timer` or `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`? Would you like to be responsible for renaming them in the case of conflicts, or is having them in explicit namespaces a good idea?

Comment: If you find C# poorly suited to the programming tasks you're using it for, luckily it's easy to switch to another language. If the designers of C# had been familiar with PHP, no doubt they would have come up with something like it.

Comment: For strings, this is actually a red herring: the most basic types have explicit aliases in C# (`string` among them) and so do not actually require importing namespaces. But for anything even slightly more advanced than that, C# has opted to go for consistency over brevity. IDE support mostly makes this a non-issue.

Comment: i dont really understand this. what is the reason that I cant simply just do `Console.WriteLine("hi")` in C# without having to declare `Using System`?

Comment: Also note that unlike PHP, a lot of the .NET Framework itself can actually be written in C# -- and *is* written in C#. That is, there are legitimate use cases for files that *don't* use `using System` and *don't* import *any* system libraries (by telling the compiler to omit them), so they can actually define and implement types living in `System` without conflict. This would be impossible if everything was pulled in without qualification.

Comment: Because `Console` resides in the `System` namespace. You can use `System.Console.WriteLine("hi");` without any `using`.

Comment: @volumeone Because C# is not, and is not intended to be, a language like PHP. You need to engage with each new language as it is, as a product of its own unique intent and design process, not on the assumption that they're all broken versions of PHP with funny syntax.

Comment: I only mentioned PHP because its popular and interpreted. I actually use ColdFusion that runs on JVM. There are no import or Using syntax in that

Comment: Ultimately, it's a design difference between a language cleanly separated from the framework that contains the library classes and one that isn't. C# isn't "permitted" to assume that things like database connections even exist (let alone what they're named, or assume that every developer will take care to uniquely name their classes), a language like ColdFusion (which comes with most stuff out of the box and is designed to support writing compact code for individual web pages) has much greater freedom to be terse and implicit.

Comment: @volumeone The point is equally valid for Cold Fusion. The answer to "why isn't this hammer a screwdriver?" is, "they didn't set out to make a screwdriver, they needed a hammer instead".

Comment: Your comments don't answer the question though... you're just saying thats the way it is. And ColdFusion and .Net achieve the same things. The question would therefore be why does C#'s hammer require you to attach the metal head everytime you want to use it whereas ColdFusion PHP etc do not... especially when it cannot be used as a hammer without the metal head.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just how C# and .NET work.

If you want your code to use a type, then in the IL (bytecode) it gets compiled into you need to mention its entire name. You cannot say `String`, or `Console`, because **those types do not exist**; their names are `System.String` and `System.Console`, respectively.

This is how .NET was designed from the ground on up; using parts of the name for categorization. This translates to "namespaces", see [Namespaces (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/).

A [using directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive) makes part of a namespace available in the file where it is used, so you don't have to repeat the entire name:

```
using System;

class Foo
{
    String Bar;
}
```

Now the C# compiler checks all namespaces in the file, and finds `System.String`.

But `System.String` isn't that good of an example, because C# has a built-in alias for it: `string` (lowercase `s`). The code below is equivalent:

```
class Foo
{
    string Bar;
}
```

Part of your confusion also seems to stem from the belief that a using directive is the same as a reference, but that's a common misbelief.

By default, if you compile a C# project, it does already *reference* the core library (mscorlib, BCL, give it a name), so the types therein are accessible to your code. If it wouldn't, the compiler would complain about not being able to find `System.String`. It does reference it, so it knows where to find the type and what it looks like, but you *still* need to add a using directive or use its full name.

See [-nostdlib (C# Compiler Options)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/nostdlib-compiler-option).